# TCP wrappers deny user@hostname

Tags: linux, tcp, wrapper

Im trying to deny a specific user on a machine using TCP wrappers
in /etc/hosts.deny  there is

sshd : tom@192.168.48.184

when i ssh from 192.168.48.184  using user tom it goes thru , im missing something?

Comment: SO is for _programming_ questions; this is about Linux configuration, so it is way off-topic for so and belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Insert a line:

DenyUsers username1 username2 username3 username4

Referring to #man sshd_config:

```
DenyUsers
separated by spaces. Login is disallowed for user names that
match one of the patterns. â*â and â?â can be used as wildcards
in the patterns. Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID
is not recognized. By default, login is allowed for all users.
If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are
separately checked, restricting logins to particular users from
particular hosts.
```

Save it and restart SSH services.

/etc/init.d/sshd restart

Read more: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.in/2008/08/how-to-deny-ssh-access-for-certain-user.html#ixzz2gjLPH8yH

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Answer (score 0):

The only secure (read: correct) way to do this is to disable password/keyboard-interactive login methods and add `deny-from` option to all Tom's authorized keys.